# Why isn't fetch_sub a release operation?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency, memory-barriers

Quoted from **C++ Concurrency in Action** $Listing 5.9

> A `fetch_sub`
>   operation with `memory_order_acquire` semantics doesn’t synchronize-with anything,
>   even though it stores a value, because it isn’t a release operation. Likewise, a store
>   can’t synchronize-with a `fetch_or` with `memory_order_release` semantics, because
>   the read part of the `fetch_or` isn’t an acquire operation.

It's hard to understand the paragraph above for me. If a  `fetch_sub`
operation with `memory_order_acquire` semantics doesn’t synchronize-with anything, why does the interface of `fetch_sub` leave a memory order parameter for us as following?

`T fetch_sub( T arg, std::memory_order order = std::memory_order_seq_cst ) noexcept;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. "synchronize with" is unidirectional and not commutative. "A synchronizes with B" doesn't imply "B synchronizes with A" (in fact, quite the opposite), unlike what one might expect from English. Thus, a `memory_order_acquire` RMW operation can't synchronize with anything, but a `memory_order_release` store synchronizes with a `memory_order_acquire` RMW operation that takes the value read from the store. Similarly, while a `memory_order_release` store doesn't synchronize with a `memory_order_release` RMW, a `memory_order_release` RMW can synchronize with a `memory_order_acquire` load.
2. `memory_order_acq_rel`.

Comment: So only `release` could synchronize with `acquire`, is that true?

Comment: @bigxiao, `memory_order_seq_cst` also synchronizes with `acquire`.